# Aligning text with Font Awesome icons

Tags: vertical-alignment, align, alignment, fontawesome

I am trying to align some text up with various font awesome icons so that they are vertically-aligned (i.e. the text should be at the vertical middle of the icon).

This is the code I have currently:

```
{\LARGE \faInbox} \href{some email}{some email} \quad
{\LARGE \faPhone} (555) 555-5555 \quad
{\LARGE \faLinkedinSquare} \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/somelinkedin/}{somelinkedin} \quad
{\LARGE \faGithub} \href{https://github.com/username}{username} \quad
{\LARGE \faStackOverflow} \href{https://stackoverflow.com/users/12584129/someuser}{someuser} \quad
```

When rendered, the output looks like this:

[image]

I wish to center the text vertically in line with the Font Awesome icons.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LIke this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} 

\begin{document}

\noindent\raisebox{-0.3\height}{\LARGE \faInbox} \href{some email}{some email} \quad
\raisebox{-0.3\height}{\LARGE \faPhone} (555) 555-5555 \quad
\raisebox{-0.3\height}{\LARGE \faLinkedinSquare} \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/somelinkedin/}{somelinkedin} \quad
\raisebox{-0.3\height}{\LARGE \faGithub} \href{https://github.com/username}{username} \\
\raisebox{-0.3\height}{\LARGE \faStackOverflow} \href{https://stackoverflow.com/users/12584129/someuser}{someuser} \quad

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to help!