# How to center Font Awesome in table?

Tags: tables, fonts, spacing, vertical-alignment, center

There are some very [advanced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63364815/vertical-alignment-of-text-in-a-table-in-latex-overleaf) [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells) that I can't figure out how to adapt to this situation.

When I do the following the text in the second column does get vertically centred for some reason.

**Question**

Can someone figure out how vertically centre both columns?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cl}
{\huge \faIcon{envelope}} \hspace{0.5em}         & xxx\\\\
{\huge \faIcon{phone-square-alt}} \hspace{0.5em} & xxx\\\\
{\huge \faIcon{trophy}} \hspace{0.5em}           & xxx y.o.\\\\
{\huge \faIcon{map-marker-alt}} \hspace{0.5em}   & xxx
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**Update**

The problem seams to be related to font awesome?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{Q[c,m]Q[l,m]]}
\hline
{\huge \faIcon{envelope}} \hspace{0.5em}         & xxx\\\\
\hline
{\huge \faIcon{phone-square-alt}} \hspace{0.5em} & xxx\\\\
{\huge \faIcon{trophy}} \hspace{0.5em}           & xxx y.o.\\\\
{\huge \faIcon{map-marker-alt}} \hspace{0.5em}   & xxx
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While the accepted answer in the question you linked question looks complicated, it directly links to another answer using `tabularray` package which should be very simple: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/how-to-vertically-center-the-text-of-the-cells/611601#611601

Comment: @user202729 I wish I could understand the example...

Comment: You should be able to easily find the documentation of that LaTeX package on CTAN to look up the options passed to the environment.

Comment: @user202729 Great documentation indeed. The problem seams to be related to font awesome? Now updated OP.

Comment: This is unexpected. Anyway it's probably the same reason as https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/653498/250119...?

Comment: The problem isn't font awesome per se but a `{\huge }` character in a cell and a normal character in the other cell, where both are on baseline… https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/673903/23418 I would go with `\raisebox{}{}` trials too https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/673871/23418

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vertical centering is not well defined when a single row of text is concerned: what do you take as vertical center? With respect to lowercase letters? Or those with neither ascenders nor descenders? Or those with both?

On the other hand, `fontawesome` symbols have different ideas of where they sit on:

```
\_\faIcon{envelope}\_\faIcon{phone-square-alt}\_\faIcon{trophy}\_\faIcon{map-marker-alt}\_
```

[image]

I redefined the `\_` command for this purpose in order to show precisely the baseline at its top edge.

An answer might be to adopt as vertical center the math axis, where fraction lines sit on. As the picture shows, the math axis is at the center of the capital X.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\newcommand{\myfa}[1]{%
  $\vcenter{\hbox{\huge\faIcon{#1}}}$%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c@{}cl}
$\frac{\quad}{}$&
\myfa{envelope}\hspace{0.5em}         & Xyz\\\\
$\frac{\quad}{}$&
\myfa{phone-square-alt}\hspace{0.5em} & Xyz\\\\
$\frac{\quad}{}$&
\myfa{trophy}\hspace{0.5em}           & Xyz y.o.\\\\
$\frac{\quad}{}$&
\myfa{map-marker-alt}\hspace{0.5em}   & Xyz
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieve by using `array.sty` and the column format `m`. and the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{m{5pc}m{5pc}}%change the value as you like
{\huge \faIcon{envelope}} \hspace{0.5em}         & xxx\\\\
{\huge \faIcon{phone-square-alt}} \hspace{0.5em} & xxx\\\\
{\huge \faIcon{trophy}} \hspace{0.5em}           & xxx y.o.\\\\
{\huge \faIcon{map-marker-alt}} \hspace{0.5em}   & xxx
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is still not vertical centred. Have a look https://imgur.com/a/jIl1phX .

Answer (score 5):

A possible solution with a TikZ matrix:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%no more needed
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[
    matrix of nodes,
    column 1/.style={nodes={font=\huge, anchor=center}},
    column 2/.style={nodes={anchor=west}}
    ]
    {
    \faIcon{envelope} &[.5em] xxx\\
    \faIcon{phone-square-alt} & xxx\\
    \faIcon{trophy} & xxx y.o.\\
    \faIcon{map-marker-alt}  & xxx\\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good idea to use a matrix!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not a nice solution, but you could manually raise the text in the second column a bit:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={c|[1cm,white]l},
  column{1}={font=\huge},
}
\faIcon{envelope}          & \raisebox{1.4ex}{xxx}\\
\faIcon{phone-square-alt}  & \raisebox{1.4ex}{xxx}\\
\faIcon{trophy}            & \raisebox{1.4ex}{xxx y.o.}\\
\faIcon{map-marker-alt}    & \raisebox{1.4ex}{xxx}\\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(the redlines are just for visualisation)

Comment: A similar approach here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/521571/9179